Static type checking for union type and pattern matching
In functional languages like Ocaml/Haskell/… I can type something like:
type expr =
    | Nb of float
    | Add of expr * expr
    | Soust of expr * expr
    | Mult of expr * expr
    | Div of expr * expr
    | Opp of expr

let rec eval x = match x with
    | Nb n -> n
    | Add (e1, e2) -> (eval e1) +. (eval e2)
    | Soust (e1, e2) -> (eval e1) -. (eval e2)
    | Mult (e1, e2) -> (eval e1) *. (eval e2)
    | Div (e1, e2) -> (eval e1) /. (eval e2)
    | Opp n -> -. (eval n)

And once my code compiles, I will be guaranteed that for any x of type expr, eval x will always produce an output of type float. This notably implies that my pattern matching was not forgetting any cases, so if latter I add a new item in the expr type, it will fail to compile until I add this new case in the pattern matching.
Sadly I can't find anything in python that would provide such a strong guarantee, including with Python 10's typing system… Am I missing something?

Haha, nope, Python's type system is nowhere close to the completeness of that provided by Ocaml/Haskell. If you want a language with match that could provide something similar, Rust provides something like this via enums.

@metatoaster ok thanks, but it's really sad, seems like python already has a notion of Union's type, it is just missing a notion of pattern maching now…

Hum, just found https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#exhaustiveness-checks that seems to be exactly what I need

@metatoaster turns out it is in fact possible, see my answer ;-)

Partially possible is really my point - mypy punted the problem to the return statement check, the point about incompleteness still stands as it will rear its ugly head if instead each arm doesn't return but rather does a side-effect. In this case the omission of an arm is in fact allowed, which isn't allowed in stricter languages.

@metatoaster oh, good point, I'll add it in my answer

Yeah, with this I also can't help but also updated my gist to include this example to document all the incompleteness I've came across with Python's type hinting and ecosystem.  Anyway you provided a good Q&A on this topic.

I was quite surprised to see that this feature is actually possible!! (at least using python 3.11, not tried before)
This is enabled thanks to https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#exhaustiveness-checks that provides a match construction that must pass type checking.
Execute the following code with $ python foo.py and run the type checking with $ mypy --strict foo.py.
Demo:
### Define our types

# See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17139 to get a nicer
# syntax once the bug is solved

class Mult:
    # Expr is not yet defined, so we use forward references
    # https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references
    left: 'Expr'
    right: 'Expr'
    def __init__(self, left:'Expr', right:'Expr'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Add:
    # Expr is not yet defined, so we use forward references
    # https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references
    left: 'Expr'
    right: 'Expr'
    def __init__(self, left:'Expr', right:'Expr'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Const:
    val: int
    def __init__(self, val:int):
        self.val = val

Expr = Const | Add | Mult

### Define our functions

def my_eval(e : Expr) -> int:
    match e:
        case Const():
            return e.val
        case Add():
            return my_eval(e.left) * my_eval(e.right)
        case Mult():
            return my_eval(e.left) + my_eval(e.right)

### Use them
        
print(my_eval(Const(42)))
print(my_eval(Add(Const(42),Const(45))))

$ python foo.py
42
1890
$ mypy --strict foo.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

If you decide now to remove one item, for instance by commenting the Add() case, you get an error (I have to admit, not extremely clear):
$ mypy --strict foo2.py
foo2.py:37: error: Missing return statement  [return]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

TODO
It would be great to find a simpler interface to define types, notably I found
class Mult(tuple[int, int]):
    pass

but it does not seem to be working so far inside mypy https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17139
Caveats
Note that this method has a few drawbacks. Notably, as pointed in comments (I filled a bug report here), if the return type is None (say you want to return nothing) like def my_eval(e : Expr) -> None, then the test will pass even if you remove a case:
# Execute with "python foo.py" and
# run the type checking with "mypy --strict foo.py"


### Define our types

# See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17139 to get a nicer
# syntax once the bug is solved

class Mult:
    # Expr is not yet defined, so we use forward references
    # https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references
    left: 'Expr'
    right: 'Expr'
    def __init__(self, left:'Expr', right:'Expr'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Add:
    # Expr is not yet defined, so we use forward references
    # https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references
    left: 'Expr'
    right: 'Expr'
    def __init__(self, left:'Expr', right:'Expr'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Const:
    val: int
    def __init__(self, val:int):
        self.val = val

Expr = Const | Add | Mult

### Define our functions
x = 0

def my_eval(e : Expr) -> None:
    match e:
# This should fail: still it works
#        case Const():
#            print(e.val)
        case Add():
            print("(")
            my_eval(e.left)
            print(") + (")
            my_eval(e.right)
            print(")")
        case Mult():
            print("(")
            my_eval(e.left)
            print(") + (")
            my_eval(e.right)
            print(")")

### Use them

my_eval(Add(Const(42),Const(45)))


Note also that this does not prevent the function from raising an Exception, or never ending https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17140

Just a suggestion to improve terseness: dataclass decorator can be used to allow the omission of the __init__ for each of the demo classes (which I used in the gist I linked in a comment on the question).
